# JSP+HTML with newlines - Get it as string, and remove "new lines"

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, intellij-idea

I am currenly making a little HTML overlay, using IntelliJ IDEA, which i want to be handled by the client (because of varnish cache).

So what i would like to do is the following, and its working (nearly):

Get the template code (html, jsp, el) into a variable, is fairly simple:

```
<c:set var="overlayHtml"><c:import url="/directory/myOverlay.jsp" /></c:set>
```

Then i insert it into a javascript like so, and append it:

```
var advertisementHtml = '${overlayHtml}';
$("body").append(advertisementHtml);
```

My problem is that my HTML string from the jsp is comming out with "new lines" in it. Like so:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div>HERE IS MY OVERLAY</div>
    <div>Another div</div>
</div>
```

And this, the javascript cannot handle, and therefor doesnt fire. I would like to be able to remove these new lines, so that the HTML comes out in one line, like so:

```
<div id="overlay"><div>HERE IS MY OVERLAY</div><div>Another div</div></div>
```

The problem lies in the JSP, and i need to remove the "new lines" before i inject the variable into the javascript.

Ive tried replacing HTML new line hex, and decimal unicode, ive tried replacing \n \r with an empty string, which didnt work either. Im outta luck.

How can i beat these evil new lines? (without having to make IntelliJ comments, or writing my HTML in a single line manually?)

Comment: So i have done some debugging. And i chose to log the complete char array of the string i get from the jsp.

And this is where it gets weird. I have surrounded each char with double-quotes. Is does like so: char: "" but the empty-char inside, actually breaks the line in my log file aswell.

Comment: So basically im an idiot. I had the wrong sorting of the line breaks in my regex. When i do a replace on \r, then another replace on \n, it all works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the sorting of the line breaks.

```
String newString = overlayHtml.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
```

Alternatively one could do:

```
String newString = overlayHtml.replaceAll("\\r", "");
newString = newString.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could replace the new lines with null:

```
advertisementHtml.replace( /\n/g, "" )
```

Comment: I will try this in JSP instead of javascript, as the problem is with the JSP variable. (the javascript breaks as soon as i try to set the variable).